# React Native List performance

Tags: performance, list, reactjs, listview, react-native

I have a FlatList inside of a Modal in my application the Flatlist is filled with ListItem components from 'react-native-elements'.

The ListItems just have a title and an onPress method and nothing else, but the list has 250-300 items. The list is very laggy. I understand that is going to happen with a lot of items, but with the list I cant scroll to the bottom immediately. I can scroll a certain distance then it loads up the next few items then scroll a bit more then load a bit etc. This makes picking an item lower on the list or at the bottom incredibly slow.

My data is an array of { imgnames: "imglink" } objects and the list is sorted alphabetically.

I was wondering if this performance issue is going to happen no matter what because of the amount of items, or if its because it is inside of the module.

I just want to be able to scroll the entire length of the list immediately, so I can scroll to the 'M' or 'P' sections straightaway and then have a small delay while the list renders.

What would be the best list implementation for this.

FlatList Code:

```
<FlatList 
        data={this.props.list} 
        renderItem={
            ({item}) => <ListItem hideChevron = {true} onPress={() => this._setImage(item.imgLink)} title={item.key} removeClippedSubviews = {true} initialNumToRender={5}/>
  }/>
```

Comment: have you tried setting [Initial Number To Render](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender)?

Comment: @bennygenel yes I have i have it set to 250 currently and I have this issue, I dont know if there is a limit to that setting but it seems to only load 5-20 at a time

Comment: You should set it to a small number so the FlatList renders fast and then when you scroll down you don't have a performance issue.

Comment: @bennygenel I just tried with setting it to 5 but i still get stop/start scrolling instead of being able to scroll straight to the bottom smoothly

Comment: Did you check [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#removeclippedsubviews)

Comment: @bennygenel I just added and it feels a lot faster but it still has the stop/start scrolling. It just feels like a loads a little bit a little bit quicker with each scroll;

Comment: are you testing it on a real device or an emulator?

Comment: @bennygenel A real device my motorola moto g4 android 7.0

Comment: Its interesting that I never had a performance issue with a simple list like yours. Maybe its because of the render method of the list items.

Comment: @bennygenel I was about to try the react-native-elements list instead of the Flatlist and see if it makes a difference, I also wasnt sure if it was because the list is loaded in a modal causing the performance issue

Comment: Whats your render item function?

Comment: @bennygenel I edited the question and added the FlatList code

Comment: try adding a key prop. maybe it can help with the performance. other than that I really don't know why. I'm sorry

Comment: @bennygenel holy poop, it was because I added the initailRenderNum and removeClipping to the ListItem not the FlatList. you could write that as an actual anwer for me to accept if you like, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting [initailRenderNum](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#initialnumtorender) and [removeClipping](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#removeclippedsubviews) props should help with the performance problems of the FlatList.

Example:

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.props.list} 
    removeClippedSubviews={true} 
    initialNumToRender={5}
    renderItem={
        ({item}) => <ListItem hideChevron={true} onPress={() => this._setImage(item.imgLink)} title={item.key} />
  }/>
```